# how to utilize browser libraries in node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering, isomorphic-javascript

I'm developing a React App with server side rendering.

In the client I'm using libraries that uses the document object, and so when I try to run my code in the server side node crashes since document isn't defined in that enviroment.

I'm currently solving this issue by manually checking if the document object exist and by importing the browser specific libraries only if document is defined, but this seems to me a very sloppy and unconvenient solution.

Does anybody knows a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RequireJS. This library allows to use javascript libs in the node http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html